# Beyond taking the test itself, what use is preparing for the HSK6 writing section?

Tags: chinese, hsk

Now that I've taken the Chinese HSK5 exam, my mind is turning towards HSK6.  However, I find myself lacking motivation to study for this exam, and one of the main reasons is the writing section (also called 缩写 "abridge").

> For this task, you’ll be shown a narrative passage of about 1,000 characters. The passage will be retracted after 10 minutes, and you have to rewrite it into a shorter passage of about 400 characters, based on your memorization, without adding your personal opinions. You also need to come up with a title for the passage.
> <sub>[ImproveMandarin](https://improvemandarin.com/hsk-level-6/)</sub>

If I were to begin seriously preparing for the HSK6, I would need to spend considerable time and effort improving my skills at this specialized task.  In an effort to conjure up some motivation, I'm interested in finding out...

**Question**: Beyond taking the test itself, what use is preparing for the HSK6 writing section?

Maybe some former HSK6 test-takers are able to opine on this matter.